# AKKA receive method reports error

Tags: eclipse, scala, akka

I'm working on eclipse under ubuntu 12.04 with scala 2.10 and Akka 2.2.1.

```
abstract class Node extends Actor {
  var n : Array[Node] // def n
  //..... I do not def receive here
}

class FNode extends Node {
  def receive = {
    case message => for(i <- 0 until n.size)
      n(i) ! message  // n is array. send message to all elements in n
      // ....
  }
}
```

Now, eclipse always reports

```
value ! is not a member of Node.
```

I have no idea how to fix. I waste more than 3 hours on this. I have done what I can do, but I still can not solve it.
Thanks !

Comment: Can you include the definition of n?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't send messages to an `Actor`, but only to an `ActorRef`. Change `n` to an `Array[ActorRef]` and it should work.

By the way, you can iterate collections and arrays easier and possibly more efficient, e.g.

`n foreach (ref => ref ! message)`

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that ! is defined for the ActorRef type, not the Actor type which your Node type extends.